# Css is different between dev and production in Vue with vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I have this CSS code in the Vue component:

```
.ol-btn {
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
}
.v-btn--icon.v-size--small{
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
}
```

when I run the application with "npm run serve" and open the inspector the css result is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NQ2IVD3Wvag3WZocxeKEL7GjtUDSjQ09/view?usp=sharing

but when i build the application to production the css result is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oy5CZbUP9dvv3riAZT2Mf-X29saF5JPg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you sure it's not a cache problem ? Can you refresh your web page on the production and on the dev with the command "CTRL+shift+R" and then check if you still have the same problem ?

Comment: I am sure it's not a cache problem